# What are these x86 asm instructions (rex.x, rex.wx (bad))?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, x86-64, disassembly

Re: the meaning of some instructions in disassembled C++ code (disassembled using gdb v. 13.2,
compiled using g++ v.13.1.0, with the -std=c++23, -g and -o flags).

Most of the instructions and their purpose can be found by searching books and websites on the topic, but there is one line which is only partially explained, and another which has no explanation that I could find whatsoever. The questions were inspired by the following, taken from the gdb assembly dump:

```
Dump of assembler code for function _ZdlPvy:
   0x00007ff75cdb17f0 <+0>:     jmp    *0x8a92(%rip)        # 0x7ff75cdba288 <__imp__ZdlPvy>
   0x00007ff75cdb17f6 <+6>:     nop
   0x00007ff75cdb17f7 <+7>:     nop

Dump of assembler code for function __imp__ZdlPvy:
   0x00007ff75cdba288 <+0>:     push   %rax
   0x00007ff75cdba289 <+1>:     ret
   0x00007ff75cdba28a <+2>:     rex.X
   0x00007ff75cdba28b <+3>:     rex.WX (bad)
   0x00007ff75cdba28d <+5>:     jg     0x7ff75cdba28f <__imp__ZdlPvy+7>
   0x00007ff75cdba28f <+7>:     add    %dl,%al
```

However, when I disassembled the same code 5 days later, <__imp__ZdlPvy> came out like this:

```
Dump of assembler code for function __imp__ZdlPvy:
   0x00007ff75cdba288 <+0>:     push   %rax
   0x00007ff75cdba289 <+1>:     ret
   0x00007ff75cdba28a <+2>:     stos   %al,%es:(%rdi)
   0x00007ff75cdba28b <+3>:     or     $0xf8,%al
   0x00007ff75cdba28d <+5>:     jg     0x7ff75cdba28f <__imp__ZdlPvy+7>
   0x00007ff75cdba28f <+7>:     add    %dl,%al
```

My questions are:

> what is rex.X doing here?
> what is rex.WX (bad) doing here and what does it mean?
> how is the or instruction replacing rex.WX (assuming it is)?
> how come the second disassembly, of the same routine, replaced rex.X with the stos instruction?
> Why would there be a difference from one disassembly to the next, even if the code was not
> changed and has only been run a couple of times in gdb the whole while?

For more context: _ZdlPvy was found in a routine with the following disassembly.
(One can see from the code there is a segmentation fault, caused by the insert() method. This was left in deliberately as a puzzle for me to solve.)

```
Dump of assembler code for function _ZN4MathIiED1Ev:
   0x00007ff75cdb3430 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00007ff75cdb3431 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00007ff75cdb3434 <+4>:     sub    $0x30,%rsp
   0x00007ff75cdb3438 <+8>:     mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
   0x00007ff75cdb343c <+12>:    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00007ff75cdb3443 <+19>:    jmp    0x7ff75cdb3464 <_ZN4MathIiED1Ev+52>
   0x00007ff75cdb3445 <+21>:    mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb3449 <+25>:    mov    0x8(%rax),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb344d <+29>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb3450 <+32>:    movslq %edx,%rdx
   0x00007ff75cdb3453 <+35>:    shl    $0x2,%rdx
   0x00007ff75cdb3457 <+39>:    add    %rdx,%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb345a <+42>:    movl   $0x0,(%rax)
   0x00007ff75cdb3460 <+48>:    addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00007ff75cdb3464 <+52>:    mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb3468 <+56>:    mov    (%rax),%eax
   0x00007ff75cdb346a <+58>:    cmp    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00007ff75cdb346d <+61>:    jl     0x7ff75cdb3445 <_ZN4MathIiED1Ev+21>
   0x00007ff75cdb346f <+63>:    mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb3473 <+67>:    movq   $0x0,0x8(%rax)
   0x00007ff75cdb347b <+75>:    mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb347f <+79>:    mov    0x8(%rax),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb3483 <+83>:    test   %rax,%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb3486 <+86>:    je     0x7ff75cdb3495 <_ZN4MathIiED1Ev+101>
   0x00007ff75cdb3488 <+88>:    mov    $0x4,%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb348d <+93>:    mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb3490 <+96>:    call   0x7ff75cdb17f0 <_ZdlPvy>
   0x00007ff75cdb3495 <+101>:   nop
   0x00007ff75cdb3496 <+102>:   add    $0x30,%rsp
   0x00007ff75cdb349a <+106>:   pop    %rbp
   0x00007ff75cdb349b <+107>:   ret
```

And this pops up in the following main() disassembly:

```
main (argc=1, args=0x7297a0) at Try_Out.cpp:275
275             pointier.insert(0, 5);
Dump of assembler code for function main(int, char**):
   0x00007ff75cdb16d0 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00007ff75cdb16d1 <+1>:     push   %rbx
   0x00007ff75cdb16d2 <+2>:     sub    $0x48,%rsp
   0x00007ff75cdb16d6 <+6>:     lea    0x40(%rsp),%rbp
   0x00007ff75cdb16db <+11>:    mov    %ecx,0x20(%rbp)
   0x00007ff75cdb16de <+14>:    mov    %rdx,0x28(%rbp)
   0x00007ff75cdb16e2 <+18>:    call   0x7ff75cdb18c7 <__main>
   0x00007ff75cdb16e7 <+23>:    movl   $0x2,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00007ff75cdb16ee <+30>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb16f2 <+34>:    mov    $0x1,%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb16f7 <+39>:    mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb16fa <+42>:    call   0x7ff75cdb33f0 <_ZN4MathIiEC1Ei>
=> 0x00007ff75cdb16ff <+47>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb1703 <+51>:    mov    $0x5,%r8d
   0x00007ff75cdb1709 <+57>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb170e <+62>:    mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb1711 <+65>:    call   0x7ff75cdb33c0 <_ZN4MathIiE6insertEii>
   0x00007ff75cdb1716 <+70>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb171a <+74>:    mov    $0xa,%r8d
   0x00007ff75cdb1720 <+80>:    mov    $0x1,%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb1725 <+85>:    mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb1728 <+88>:    call   0x7ff75cdb33c0 <_ZN4MathIiE6insertEii>
   0x00007ff75cdb172d <+93>:    lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb1731 <+97>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb1736 <+102>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb1739 <+105>:   call   0x7ff75cdb3390 <_ZN4MathIiE4at_vEi>
   0x00007ff75cdb173e <+110>:   mov    %eax,%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb1740 <+112>:   mov    0x3c99(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ff75cdb53e0 <__fu0__ZSt4cout>
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--c
   0x00007ff75cdb1747 <+119>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb174a <+122>:   call   0x7ff75cdb1800 <_ZNSolsEi>
   0x00007ff75cdb174f <+127>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb1752 <+130>:   lea    0x38f7(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ff75cdb5050
   0x00007ff75cdb1759 <+137>:   mov    %rax,%rdx
   0x00007ff75cdb175c <+140>:   call   0x7ff75cdb17f8 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc>
   0x00007ff75cdb1761 <+145>:   mov    %rax,%rbx
   0x00007ff75cdb1764 <+148>:   lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb1768 <+152>:   mov    $0x1,%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb176d <+157>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb1770 <+160>:   call   0x7ff75cdb3390 <_ZN4MathIiE4at_vEi>
   0x00007ff75cdb1775 <+165>:   mov    %eax,%edx
   0x00007ff75cdb1777 <+167>:   mov    %rbx,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb177a <+170>:   call   0x7ff75cdb1800 <_ZNSolsEi>
   0x00007ff75cdb177f <+175>:   lea    0x38d5(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ff75cdb505b
   0x00007ff75cdb1786 <+182>:   mov    %rax,%rdx
   0x00007ff75cdb1789 <+185>:   mov    0x3c50(%rip),%rax        # 0x7ff75cdb53e0 <__fu0__ZSt4cout>
   0x00007ff75cdb1790 <+192>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb1793 <+195>:   call   0x7ff75cdb17f8 <_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc>
   0x00007ff75cdb1798 <+200>:   mov    $0x7a120,%ecx
   0x00007ff75cdb179d <+205>:   call   0x7ff75cdb2eb0 <usleep>
   0x00007ff75cdb17a2 <+210>:   mov    $0x0,%ebx
   0x00007ff75cdb17a7 <+215>:   lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb17ab <+219>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb17ae <+222>:   call   0x7ff75cdb3430 <_ZN4MathIiED1Ev>
   0x00007ff75cdb17b3 <+227>:   mov    %ebx,%eax
   0x00007ff75cdb17b5 <+229>:   jmp    0x7ff75cdb17d1 <main(int, char**)+257>
   0x00007ff75cdb17b7 <+231>:   mov    %rax,%rbx
   0x00007ff75cdb17ba <+234>:   lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb17be <+238>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb17c1 <+241>:   call   0x7ff75cdb3430 <_ZN4MathIiED1Ev>
   0x00007ff75cdb17c6 <+246>:   mov    %rbx,%rax
   0x00007ff75cdb17c9 <+249>:   mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x00007ff75cdb17cc <+252>:   call   0x7ff75cdb2e60 <_Unwind_Resume>
   0x00007ff75cdb17d1 <+257>:   add    $0x48,%rsp
   0x00007ff75cdb17d5 <+261>:   pop    %rbx
   0x00007ff75cdb17d6 <+262>:   pop    %rbp
   0x00007ff75cdb17d7 <+263>:   ret
```

All of this was disassembled from the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <memory>

template <typename T> class Math
{
    public:
        int size = 2; T* ptr;               
        Math (int size) 
        {   T* ptr = new T(*ptr)   ;}
        T at_v         (int place)           
        {    return ptr[place]     ;}
        void insert    (int place, int value)         
        {   ptr[place] = value     ;}
};      
int main()
{                                               
    int size = 2            ;
    Math <int> pointier(1)  ;
    pointier.insert(0, 5)   ;
    pointier.insert(1, 10)  ;   

    std::cout << pointier.at_v(0) << " and also " << pointier.at_v(1) ;         
    std::cout << "\n\n"; usleep(500000)               ; 
}
```

This is simply an inquiry about the meaning of some asm instructions, of which a search of the websites and literature available came up empty. I wish to know as it would better allow me to figure out how to debug code from the disassembly: I intend to do this debugging myself, but need assistance understanding a few lines.

Comment: It's a REX prefix without an opcode following it.  And `{bad}` is usually an invalid opcode, IIRC.  You might be disassembling ASCII data; REX prefixes are in the range 0x40-0x4F.  Or some other non-code memory, or at a bad starting (not an instruction boundary) in `.text`.  **Have GDB show you the machine-code as well as disassembly, using `disas /r`**  Then you can try to guess about what else the bytes might mean.

Comment: Oh, `jmp    *0x8a92(%rip)` is loading a function pointer from memory, at `__imp__ZdlPvy`.  You're disassembling the bytes of that function pointer as machine code, instead of the pointed-to code.

Answer (score 1):

The disassembler can try to decode non-executable data. Machine code is just a type of data after all - so some random data can have a valid (or not so valid) machine code interpretation. You can order the disassembler to decode a data section. Code section can also sometimes contain non-executable constants between functions.

[REX](https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix) is a prefix in 64-bit x86 machine code. It actually supposed to slightly modify the meaning of the next instruction:

- `REX.W` makes the instruction 64-bit (by default, most instructions are 8-bit or 32-bit in x86)
- `REX.X` says, that one of the new registers `r8-r15` is used as an index
- `REX.WX` does both

So why did disassembler printed REX prefixes, instead of treating them as a part of the next instruction? Because the code has two REX prefixes - and that is illegal. The CPU would not accept such machine code, and will trigger an "Illegal Opcode" interrupt. That's also what `(bad)` means - bad instruction.

---

The code you look at is a Procedure Linkage Table (PLT). It contains stubs for functions, that are actually located in a dynamic library (`.so`). Dynamic libraries are loaded at runtime, so the compiler and linker cannot possibly know, where the functions will be located.

The first `jmp` is the executed code - it just reads the real address and jumps to it. Two `nop`s are for padding.

The next 8 bytes you show are a 64-bit address of a function - or rather a placeholder, where it should be written. Initially, it contains an address of a special "Find and load address from .so" function - that allows lazy loading. In runtime, that address will be overwritten with a real address of a function from `.so`.

Comment: *The next 8 bytes are a 64-bit address of a function* - The function pointer isn't contiguous with the PLT entry; it's several pages later.  Note the addresses `...cdb1xxx` for the PLT entry (for a function using early-binding so there's no push/jmp later part), vs. `...cdbaxxx`.  (The low 12 bits are the offset-within-page, so this is a-1 = 9 pages later.  This isn't objdump output; they just removed the GDB commands from two separate `disas`.   The `.plt.got` function pointer is in a separate page from the `.plt` entry so it can be R+W without exec while the `.plt` itself is RO + exec.

Comment: The function pointer isn't *in* a code section, they just told GDB to disassemble it.  But yes, other than separation of code and data being a thing, good answer.  https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix has details about REX prefixes (0x40-0x4F bytes).

Comment: @Peter Cordes Oh, I didn't notice, that the addresses are not contiguous. I've rewrote the answer to focus on a slightly different point.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for your input, it has helped my understanding a lot and has increased my interest in the more obscure facets of coding.

Comment: @user22405329 Thanks for the input. It has helped me to make a lot more sense out of what the compiler is doing, and about the nature of how C++ uses memory in general.